# connecting these two meshes together

Tags: mesh

[image]I want to neatly connect these two meshes together (the spokes on the rim)?

How can I do this? [image]

Hi everyone, I made a new rim and did what you say, but if I want to bridge the short sides it will be somehow crossed (see photo). Tried everything but couldn't get it done. What am I not doing right?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: it would help if we could see the topology, because it may allow you to simply use bridge edge loop for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, join your 2 objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

Then you can use the *LoopTools > Bridge*. First thing, open the *Preferences* panel and activate the addon called *LoopTools*, then:

- Bevel the inner edge loop, cut a hole:

[image]

- Select the edges that you want to bridge, right click > *LoopTools > Bridge*:

[image]

- Tweak the factors in the *Operator* box (*Segments* and *Strength*):

[image]

Comment: OP (or future user) might not have loop tools activated... worth adding a note on that :)

Comment: oh yes you're right, I'm going to edit

Comment: Quite likely, OP needs to join the meshes first. (Select both objects and press CTRL+J)

Comment: oops you're right too

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean, that means I have to redo the rim to make the edges match the spokes.
It is namely 5 spokes.

Comment: you can use Array + Simple Deform (Bend mode) modifiers to do the wheel, it's a non destructive method

Comment: Hi everyone, I made a new rim and did what you say, but if I want to bridge the short sides it will be somehow crossed (see photo).
Tried everything but couldn't get it done.
What am I not doing right?

Comment: hard to say, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello, it worked, I forgot to remove the faces from the rim where the loops go :)
Thanks everyone !