# How would you model a wheel type shape like this on top of a sphere?

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I can't wrap my head around it. I just combined two shapes now (the grid thing in the middle is created from an svg file) I need to know how to model something like that from scratch.

Comment: Create a circle with a triangle fan, select all the radial edges, and then checker deselect with settings so that the spokes of the wagon wheel as it were are deselected. Do a limited dissolve. Select all, and use inset faces with individual turned on. More explanation in an answer…

Comment: This seems trivial to achieve, what have you tried and where exactly are you having difficulties? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256405/modeling-complicated-wheel https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/259044/modeling-complicated-wheel-2 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216018/connecting-these-two-meshes-together

Comment: I just thought a little bit and found a solution. So its all good.